# sybase_connect() Error - "Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist"

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, freetds

When trying to connect to a SQLServer with sybase_connect(), I get the following errors:

From command line:
$> php test.php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sybase_connect() in test.php:7

Running the script through XAMPP:

> Warning: sybase_connect(): Sybase: Client message: Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 78) in test.php on line 7
>
> Warning: sybase_connect(): Sybase: Unable to connect in test.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function error() in test.php on line 7

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$server = 'server.domain.com';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pwd';

$sqlconnect = sybase_connect($server, $username, $password, 'UTF-8') or error('connect');
```

I'm running XAMPP on Mac OS, PHP 5.6.

I've tried connecting to the server through tsql on command line and it actually works (with and without specifying the port):

```
 tsql -S server.domain.com -U user 
 tsql -S server.domain.com -U user -p 1433
```

I've tried activating the extension for sybase on php.ini but still getting the same error:

```
extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
```

I've also tried a number of random things from stackoverflow answers but, to be honest, I'm completely lost here.

Comment: The `sql-server` tag denotes Microsoft SQL Server. Remove it if you are using Sybase.

Comment: As the documentation states, [sybase_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sybase-connect.php) opens a connection to a Sybase server, not sql server.

Comment: @DanGuzman it seems that the sybase extension can also be used to connect to MS SQL Server. 

It is actually configured that way on a production environment I'm trying to replicate (using sybase to allow secure connections) but, unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation on how to configure sybase on my local environment to connect to connect to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the `sybase*` functions could only connect to older versions of SQL Server, and have been removed in PHP 7.0, which will soon be the only secure version available.

I would advise using PHP's `sqlsrv_connect()`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php
...or PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks FlipperPa, we're going to explore the option of sqlsrv_connect as you suggest